# Install Bitcoin and Bitcoin cash

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, installation

How can I install on the same Ubuntu server together Bitcoin Core and Bitcoin Cash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile them from source or download their binary. Since they both use the same port, you will need to start one of them with `-listen=0` command-line argument. Please see this discussion on github for more info: https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/issues/25

**Bitcoin Core**

- Compile from source at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
- Download at https://bitcoin.org/en/download

**Bitcoin Cash***

- Compile from source at https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc or https://github.com/BitcoinUnlimited/BitcoinUnlimited.
- Download binary at https://github.com/BitcoinUnlimited/BitcoinUnlimited

* Contrary to Bitcoin Core there isnt a single authoritative implementation, so you will have to choose which one you want

Comment: With Bitcoin Core you can just specify the `-port=` parameter, either on the command line or in the .conf file.